# Run function on Ctrl + K in React TypeScript application

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working in a React TypeScript application (`v18.2.0`).

When the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> I want to run a function.

The code I have within my component at the moment is:

```
const keyDownHandler = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
  if (event.key === "k" && event.key === "Control") {
    console.log("You just pressed Control and K!");
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler);
});
```

However, TypeScript isn't happy. I get the error:

> TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"k"' and '"Control"' have no overlap.

Which I guess makes sense, since you can't have `.key` be `k` and `Control` at the same time. But then I'm stuck, I don't know how to check if both keys were pressed together.

Also, in Chrome, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> puts focus into the Chrome URL bar, how do I stop that from happening? I know they've done it on Tailwindcss docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try:

```js
const keyDownHandler = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === "k") {
    console.log("You just pressed Control and K!");
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler);
});
```

`ctrlKey` can be different in different environment, so do try your code on both windows, and macos.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey

Comment: Thanks @darth-coder, good shout about testing under different operating systems. Any ideas about stopping Chrome to triggering on `Ctrl` + `k`?

Comment: Turns out, I just needed `event.preventDefault()` to stop the chrome issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `windows.addEventListener` without the return function in useEffect
you should try

You should try:

```
const keyDownHandler = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === "k") {
    console.log("You just pressed Control and K!");
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler);
  return () => {
     window.removeEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler);
  };
});
```